# How to break paragraph in columns using css3

Tags: css

can you please break paragraph in columns using css3 .I think there is some css in  which break paragraph.

Here is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/u6nLL/

```
<p>Sachin Ramesh Tendulkar (Listeni/ˌsətʃɪn tɛnˈduːlkər/; born 24 April 1973) is a former Indian cricketer widely acknowledged as the greatest batsman of the modern generation and by many as the greatest cricketer of all time.[6][7][8][9][10][11] He took up cricket at the age of eleven, made his Test debut against Pakistan at the age of sixteen, and went on to represent Mumbai domestically and India internationally for close to twenty-four years. He is the only player to have scored one hundred international centuries, the first batsman to score a double century in a One Day International, and the only player to complete more than 30,000 runs in international cricket.[12] In October 2013, he became the 16th player and first Indian to aggregate 50,000 runs in all recognized cricket (first-class, List A and Twenty20 combined).[13][14][15]</p>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "columns", you have to give more information on what you want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

```
p
{
-moz-column-count:3; /* Firefox */
-webkit-column-count:3; /* Safari and Chrome */
column-count:3;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rooseve/u6nLL/1/